# Could not understand expression - RavenDB

Tags: linq, ravendb

I have a set of deals, each of which have a list of User Ids that are allowed to access the deal.

Simply querying Raven with

```
var theId = 6;
var deals = session.Query<Deal>().Where(x => x.UserIds.Contains(theId)).ToList();
```

Where the Deal class looks like

```
public class Deal {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public List<Int32> UserIds = new List<Int32>();
}
```

Results in the exception

```
Could not understand expression: .Where(x => x.UserIds.Contains(value(Deals_Manager.Controllers.DealsController+<>c__DisplayClass4).theId))
```

Inner exception

```
{"Expression type not supported: value(Deals_Manager.Controllers.DealsController+<>c__DisplayClass4).theId"}
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Contains` inside a `Where` is an extremely difficult expression tree to convert to the proper Lucene expression of `UserIds:6`, let alone when you introduce a closure to bring the outside variable into the lambda expression. (The closure is what's making your exception look so goofy, by the way.)

It's further complicated by the fact that your model is a List which has its own special version of `Contains` which is different than the `IEnumerable` version.

Try this on for size instead:

```
var theId = 6;
var deals = session.Query<Deal>()
    .Where(x => x.UserIds.Any(id => id == theId))
    .ToList();
```

For any expression tree that Raven cannot understand, just try to think of it in more primitive terms.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about this, but solved the problem weeks ago using exactly this. Thanks